# How to leave everday objects / surfaces "Shining / Gleaming" after cleaning?

Tags: cleaning

I just wondered if anyone had any known "lifehacks" for leaving everyday household objects such as work-surfaces, windows, tiles, etc "shiny / gleaming" after cleaning. Reason for asking is I recently cleaned our apartment instead of our cleaner and got told it looked clean but things don't look "shiny" like how the cleaner does it and used exact same cleaning products...

Answer (score 2):

I noticed our cleaner was able to get things shiny and had a look what she was doing. She has a big stock of rags, mostly made of old cut strips of tee-shirts, but also what I would call dusters. I think the key is choose material that is slightly absorbent, but nothing that will drop lint. She uses these to dry and polish the surfaces, and has lots of them so she can keep changing them for dry ones. But you need to wipe when the surfaces are still a bit damp, or they dry with smudges. And she washes the rags between visits. I find this works on lots of different surfaces, including glass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll definitely give this a try and see how it turns out!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely try using toothpaste on objects like windows and benches if you don't have any other applicants. Just be mindful to wipe it clean with a damp cloth so it doesn't get sticky and you have enough toothpaste.